# Need help removing item from ArrayList

Tags: java

Im attempting to remove an object form an array list but if fails everytime.
Im using a function to add and a seperate one to remove. The add function is working but the remove is not. I cant see where it is going wrong and failing.

```
public void unregister( Basics classToRemove){
 if(checkIsRegistered(classToRemove)){
    getClassList().remove(classToRemove);
    System.out.println(getClassList().remove(classToRemove));
    System.out.println("You have unregistered from " + classToRemove.className + " class.");
            setTotalTuition();
        } else{
            System.out.println("\nYou are not currently registered for " + classToRemove.className + " class.\n");
        }
}
```

```
public void register(Basics classToAdd){
  if(!checkIsRegistered(classToAdd)){
    getClassList().add(classToAdd);
    System.out.println("You have registered for " + classToAdd.className + " class.");
    setTotalTuition();
    }else{
        System.out.println("\nYou are already registered for " + classToAdd.className + " class.\n");
    }
}
```

I have attempted using this.arrayList to remove the object and using getters to get the object and remove it.

Comment: what is the error it fails with?

Comment: You should add method details of checkIsRegistered, getClassList and setTotalTuition for this code to work

Comment: Did you implement `equals()`?

Comment: Assuming `remove` method retuns the removed item, you should do it as `Basics class = getClassList().remove(classToRemove);
System.out.println(class);`

Answer (score 2):

You can not just print a class-object with `System.out.printline`. I assume you want to print the attributes of the class, however you are printing the memory address of the object.

Additionally, this doesn't make sense to me:

```
getClassList().remove(classToRemove);
System.out.println(getClassList().remove(classToRemove));
```

You can't access and print an Object you just removed.

If this is not helpful, consider providing a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explaining what exactly is not working.